# Auto Passing a "q" before a Y on a command line

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to download the teamspeak 3 client and accept the license agreement  routine all at the same time. I know how to pass a “yes” before the script but the routine requires me to press <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit the “license agreement” before clicking the <kbd>Y</kbd> key to start the unpacking of the client.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/test/ts3_client_files
wget http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.19.4/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.19.4.run
yes 'y' | ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.19.4.run
```

As you can see, the routine requires the pressing of <kbd>Q</kbd> first. When I press <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> is then pressed automatically and the files decompress.

```
+ cd /home/test/ts3_client_files
+ wget http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.19.4/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.19.4.run
--2016-09-05 08:33:26--  http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.19.4/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.19.4.run
Resolving dl.4players.de (dl.4players.de)... 85.25.26.25, 85.25.26.26, 85.25.26.27
Connecting to dl.4players.de (dl.4players.de)|85.25.26.25|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 37054436 (35M) [application/x-makeself]
Saving to: ‘TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.19.4.run’

100%[=============================>] 37,054,436  9.56MB/s   in 7.1s

2016-09-05 08:33:34 (4.96 MB/s) - ‘TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.19.4.run’ saved [37054436/37054436]

+ chmod 0700 TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.19.4.run
+ yes y
+ ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.19.4.run
Welcome to the TeamSpeak 3 Client for Linux on amd64 installer

In order to install this software you are required to accept the license
agreement, please press return to view the license.

You can scroll with the arrow keys and quit the viewer by pressing 'q'.
[RETURN]
Please type y to accept, n otherwise: Creating directory TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeamSpeak 3 Client for Linux on amd64  100%
+ exit
```

Would someone be so kind in showing me the way?

Comment: wild guess, no time to check: does `yes 'qy'` work? Otherwise, check `expect`: http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Comment: If only a *single* `y` response is required, you shouldn't need `yes`; try `printf 'qy\n'`

Comment: Rmano, your suggestion yes 'qy' did not work.
Steeldriver, your suggestion did not work either.

Checking expect

Comment: What you didn't mention is that the `q` is to be processed as a quit signal for the `less` pager that is used to display the text; it turns out that the trick here is too pass it *as a command line option to `less`* i.e. `printf '\ny\n' | LESS='+q' ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.19.4.run`

Comment: @steeldriver That makes for an answer, do you mind adding it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The <kbd>q</kbd> keypress serves as a quit signal for the pager `less`, which is explicitly used by the script:

```
read FOO
echo "$licensetxt" | less
while true
do
  MS_Printf "Please type y to accept, n otherwise: "
  read yn
  if test x"$yn" = xn; then
    keep=n
eval $finish; exit 1
    break;
  elif test x"$yn" = xy; then
    break;
  fi
done
```

And [`man less`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/less.1.html) says:

> Options are also taken from the environment variable "LESS".

Set this environment variable as follows:

```
printf '\ny\n' | LESS='+q' ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.19.4.run
```

<sub>Solution taken from [@steeldriver's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821224/auto-passing-a-q-before-a-y-on-a-command-line/980523#comment1246411_821224) and added according to [the law of @JamesTheAwesomeDude](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1323/what-prewritten-pro-forma-aka-autoreviewcomments-userscript-comments-can-we-us/1876#comment7907_1876).</sub>