# Expect script help

Tags: command-line, bash, expect

I need some help with he expect command. I am trying to unpack the teamspeak 3 Linux client automatically.

Here is my script to grab the file

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir /home/test && cd /home/test
wget http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.19.4/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.19.4.run
chmod 0777 TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.19.4.run
```

Here is my expect script that gets executed after the script above ...

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn sh TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.19.4.run
expect "\[RETURN\]"
send "\r"
expect ":"
send "q"
expect "Please type y to accept, n otherwise:"
send "y\n"
```

It does NOT uncompress and it should.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Make `send "q\r"` and `send "y\r"`, assuming the expected strings are correct.

Comment: @heemayl it appears the first one doesn't *need* the `\r` (the `q` just quits the `less` pager that's used to display the agreement); adding it just makes it present the `y/n` question twice.

Comment: @steeldriver Ahhh, makes sense. I didn't check the the script though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *seems* to work, for me (I haven't tested the final installation)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.19.4.run
expect "\[RETURN\]" {send "\r"}
expect ":" {send "q"}
expect "otherwise:" {send "y\r"}
expect eof {exit}
```

Comment: Most excellent! Thank you so very much for this answer and the other reply which bright me here. I really appreciate so very much, you have no idea.

Comment: @curiouscat you're welcome - I posted a further comment on your [original question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/821224/auto-passing-a-q-before-a-y-on-a-command-line) suggesting a way to do it without `expect` (by tricking `less` into quitting right away)